# Clear all data and turn back to default settings

Tags: javascript, jquery

Goal:
When I clickon the clear all button and the data inside of the input box should be empthy and the dropdownlist should go back to default settings that is year 2009.

Problem:
I don't know how to do in order to make the dropdownlist to go back to default when you have pressed the button?

Info:
Please remember that I do not want to make any big changes in the current javascript/jquery sourcecode  because it is used in production phase.
I would like to make a complementary to the current source code.

I tried using `<input type="reset" value="Clear alll" name="clear_all">` but it doesn't work in long term with the current source code.

Thanks!

```
http://jsbin.com/qezesohake/edit?html,js,console,output
```

```js
    function df(data) {

        $(data).find(':input').each(function () {
            switch (this.type) {
                case 'text':
 
                case 'textarea':
                    $(this).val('');
                    break;
            }
        });

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action=""" method="post">    

<fieldset>
 <input id="aaa" type="text" value="" />
 <input id="bbb" type="text" value="" />


 <select id="year">

  <option value="2010">2010</option>
  <option value="2009" selected="selected">2009</option>
  <option value="2008">2008</option>

 </select>

</fieldset>


 <input type="button" value="Clear alll" name="clear_all" onclick="df(this.form)" />                                                          
                                                          
</form>
```

Comment: Add a Reset button to your form, if that helps.

Comment: I tried using " <input type="reset" value="Clear alll" name="clear_all"> " but it doesn't work in long term.

Comment: in the current among source code.

Comment: Could you please edit the question and add the updated code snippet with the reset button. The reset button should be inside the form tag.

Comment: You don't need the JS/Jquery function on click of the reset button. It will reset automatically. Just keep input type = reset

Comment: I know about it but in this context I have done lots of testing and the conclusion is that the data will be removed after I have used page navigation. If I don't apply the javascript the input='reset' will not be working after I have used pagenavigator.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<form action="#" method="post">    

<fieldset>
 <input id="aaa" type="text" value="" />
 <input id="bbb" type="text" value="" />


 <select id="year">

  <option value="2010">2010</option>
  <option value="2009" selected="selected">2009</option>
  <option value="2008">2008</option>

 </select>

</fieldset>


 <input type="reset" value="Clear alll" name="clear_all" onclick="doSomething()">                                                         
                                                          
</form>

<script>
   function doSomething(){
     alert('Do something!');
   }
</script>
```

Comment: If possible, I would like to add the additional and the new source code in the javascript. Thank you!

Comment: @HelloWorld, Check the edit, I think this is what you want !

Comment: It works but when I apply it in the test phase and due to complication among the other source code, the type="reset" won't work to delete all the data when I use page navigator, sorry. That is the the specific javascript that I have uploaded is being created.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any javascript to clear form instead just replace your input type to `reset` button

```
 <input type="reset" value="Clear all" name="clear_all"/>
```

Comment: If possible, I would like to add the additional and the new source code in the javascript. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Reset button does not require any onClick event to be passed. It works automatically.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action=""" method="post">    
    <fieldset>
        <input id="aaa" type="text" value="" />
        <input id="bbb" type="text" value="" />
        <select id="year">
            <option value="2010">2010</option>
            <option value="2009" selected="selected">2009</option>
            <option value="2008">2008</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="reset" value="Clear alll" name="clear_all" />                                                          
</form>
```

Comment: I know about it but in this Reset button and I have done lots of testing and the conclusion is that the data will be removed after I have used page navigation. If I don't apply the javascript the input='reset' will not be working after I have used pagenavigator.